# Optimization of a query with GROUP BY clause by using indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to optimize indexes in a table that stores more than 10 Millions rows. The query that is particularly time consuming takes up to 10 seconds to load (when WHERE clause filters only about 2 Millions rows - 8 Millions must be grouped). I have created a few indexes (some of them are complex, some simpler) and tried to find out how to speed this up. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. MySQL is using optimized_5 index (based on EXPLAIN).

Here is the table's structure and the query:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geo_reverse` (
     `fid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `tablename` enum('table1','table2') NOT NULL default 'table1',
   `geo_continent` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   `geo_country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   `geo_region` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   `geo_city` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`fid`,`tablename`,`geo_continent`,`geo_country`,`geo_region`,`geo_city`),
   KEY `geo_city` (`geo_city`),
   KEY `fid` (`fid`),
   KEY `geo_region` (`geo_region`,`geo_city`),
   KEY `optimized` (`tablename`,`type`,`geo_continent`,`geo_country`,`geo_region`,`geo_city`,`fid`),
   KEY `optimized_2` (`fid`,`tablename`),
   KEY `optimized_3` (`type`,`geo_city`),
   KEY `optimized_4` (`geo_city`,`tablename`),
   KEY `optimized_5` (`tablename`,`type`,`geo_city`),
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

An example query:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS objects FROM geo_reverse WHERE tablename = 'table1' AND geo_city IN (5847207,5112771,4916894,...) GROUP BY type
```

Do you have any idea of how to speed the computation up?

Comment: have you tried with obvious index: create index idx1 on geo_reverse ( tablename, geo_city ) ?

Comment: Yes. MySQL chooses optimized_5, though. What is worth noting is that eliminating group by, the query is a bit faster (6 instead of 8 seconds), but it's still too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use the following index: (geo_city, tablename, type) - geo_city is obviously more selective than tablename, thus it should be on the left. After the condition is applied, the rest should be sorted by type for grouping.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip. I just tried it - it's even slower - more than 11 secs:( Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @FlexJack, very strange. Have you tried to run OPTIMIZE on the table? does the query use the index?

Comment: @newtover - I forced MySQL to use that index and checked its status with EXPLAIN - it is using filesort and I think this is the reason. However, I don't know why. The amount of data is too large? Should I tweak MySQL settings?

Comment: I think the right order is tablename then geo_city. Swap this order becomes a unbalanced index.

Comment: @FlexJack, how many distinct values are there in the type column in the table and after the condition is applied?

Comment: @newtover, In general, there are 43 distinct values and after quering with the condition - 15

Comment: @FlexJack, then the index on type obviously only hurts ) By the way, why do not you use a lookup table instead?

Comment: @newtover, You are absolutely right - the index you have proposed works perfectly when used without type at the end. It now takes only 1.5 sec:) Thank you very much mate!

Comment: @FlexJack, I am glad that my description helped, though you had had the index as optimized_4 =) Don't forget to remove the excess indexes.